# A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released in DynamiteModulesC

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, google-play-services, android-strictmode

I am using Strict mode and am getting a lot of this errors.

```
E/StrictMode: A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
  java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
  at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:180)
  at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:222)
  at android.app.ContextImpl.openFileOutput(ContextImpl.java:514)
  at android.content.ContextWrapper.openFileOutput(ContextWrapper.java:199)
  at bjq.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:16)
  at bip.c(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:99)
  at bje.run(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:36)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
```

These are my gradle files:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3' 
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.1'
```

Firebase

```
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4"
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4"
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.4"
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.0.4"
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4"
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4"
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.0.4"
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.7.0'
```

Google Play Services

```
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:11.0.4"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.0.4"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.4"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4"
```

Comment: That means you have to check your latest version of each API that you used.Make sure that it has already released.

Comment: I checked. All of them are latest versions